# Email: combine gradient with bulletproof background VML

Tags: html, css, email, html-email, vml

I'm having trouble finding the best way to add a gradient to my background image. As most email designers have found, Outlook is the only email client that is giving me issues.

I can't add this gradient to the image in photoshop. This background image will be dynamic based on who is opening it the email.

I tried nesting the background and the gradient but found out the hard way you can't do that. So now i'm wondering if I can have the background image and the gradient in the same VML fill element.

Here is my background image:

```
<!--[if gte mso 9]>
   <v:rect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" fill="true" stroke="false" style="width:680px;height:407px; background-position: center center !important;">
   <v:fill type="tile" src="http://i.imgur.com/Z0d2QCI.jpg"
   <v:textbox inset="0,0,0,0">
<![endif]-->
```

Would I be able to add a second fill element to this?

```
<v:fill type=gradient color="#ffffff" color2="#000000" opacity="0%" opacity2="100%" />
```

This gradient should be black to transparent with black on the top and 0% transparent on the bottom. I want it to look like this: 
[image: Background-Image]

Comment: Can you not add a gradient to each dynamic variable img wherever they are hosted?

Comment: @RichardClifford Unfortunately I wasn't able to add the gradient to each image for a few reasons, the main reason being the number of images. This was for a home searching site where properties come and go very quickly so we couldn't justify the investment to apply this affect to each image for one email campaign. Ultimately, we altered the design because this affect would not work.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think adding a second fill or background image to the same element and have it work in Outlook, but you might try **nesting** background images like this:

```
<!-- First Background : BEGIN -->
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%">
  <tr>
    <td background="https://i.imgur.com/YJOX1PC.png" bgcolor="#7bceeb" valign="top">
      <!--[if gte mso 9]>
      <v:rect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" fill="true" stroke="false" style="mso-width-percent:1000;">
        <v:fill type="tile" src="https://i.imgur.com/YJOX1PC.png" color="#7bceeb" />
        <v:textbox style="mso-fit-shape-to-text:true" inset="0,0,0,0">
      <![endif]-->
      <div>

        <!-- Second Background : BEGIN -->
        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%">
          <tr>
            <td background="https://i.imgur.com/YJOX1PC.png" bgcolor="#7bceeb" valign="top">
              <!--[if gte mso 9]>
              <v:rect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" fill="true" stroke="false" style="mso-width-percent:1000;">
                <v:fill type="tile" src="https://i.imgur.com/YJOX1PC.png" color="#7bceeb" />
                <v:textbox style="mso-fit-shape-to-text:true" inset="0,0,0,0">
              <![endif]-->
              <div>

                Content

              </div>
              <!--[if gte mso 9]>
                </v:textbox>
              </v:rect>
              <![endif]-->
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
        <!-- Second Background : END -->

      </div>
      <!--[if gte mso 9]>
        </v:textbox>
      </v:rect>
      <![endif]-->
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<!-- First Background : END -->
```

Comment: As mentioned in the question already, nesting background images will not work. This has already been tried. The second background fill will be offset in outlook 2007, 2010 and 2013 and display in the top left of the email.

Comment: You can't nest, but you can use absolute positioning. If you completely close the first VML, and then do the second (so that it's not nesting), you *may* be able to put one over the other (untested). See this where I did it for a VML button over a background: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70179090/8942566

Comment: Desktop Win Outlook [doesn't support `position`](https://www.caniemail.com/search/?s=position), so absolute positioning won't work.